# Django Rest Framework and Auth: How to override UserDetailsView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using `django-rest-auth` for API endpoints for my custom user model. Getting user details, I send a `GET` request to `/rest-auth/user/`. This works fine with an authenticated user, but is forbidden for an unauthenticated user marked by a `403 Forbidden` error.

However, I want other users to be able to view each other's details. How can I change this?

This test is the one which demonstrates this error:

```
def test_get_user(self):
        # /rest-auth/user/ (GET)
        # params: username, first_name, last_name
        # returns: pk, username, email, first_name, last_name
        client = APIClient()
        client.login(username=self.user2.username, 
                     password=self.user2.password)

        path = "/rest-auth/user/"
        user_data = {
            "username": self.username,
        }
        expected_response = {
            "pk": self.id,
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email,
            "first_name": '',
            "last_name": '',
        }

        response = client.get(path, user_data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, expected_response)
```

EDIT:
I tried to override the permissions of UserDetailsView, yet I failed to do so properly. How do I do this correctly?

```
from rest_auth import views
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly


class CustomUserDetailsView(views.UserDetailsView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )
```

Comment: what are the default permission classes in your settings? What are they on the view / viewset?

Comment: I've updated this @Pythonista to try to override the permission class, which defaults to `IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: How about `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-rest-auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `/rest-auth/user/` only allow you to get details of the authenticated user.

```
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
"""
Reads and updates UserModel fields
Accepts GET, PUT, PATCH methods.

Default accepted fields: username, first_name, last_name
Default display fields: pk, username, email, first_name, last_name
Read-only fields: pk, email

Returns UserModel fields.
"""
serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Adding this method since it is sometimes called when using
    django-rest-swagger
    https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/275
    """
    return get_user_model().objects.all()
```

if you want unauthenticated users to read all user objects you have write your own view.

**serializers.py**

```
User = get_user_model()
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetailApiView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
path('api/users/<int:pk>',views.UserDetailApiView.as_view(),name='user')
```